# How to manage a large number of permissions?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, acl

I am working on a large Java EE web-app with CRM functionalit and we are looking for a security approach/library/solution/anything. Basic role-based security won't work since access control must be based on both role *and* hierarchy, but must be optionally customisable per document. Because there will be confidential and proprietary information stored, it is a requirement that the security works properly.

**Example:** To use department store, shelf <s>stalkers</s> stockers can create reports that other stockers can read ***only if*** they are in the same department. Now their department manager can read/write/update/delete all reports written by stockers and write reports that all others department managers can read but not see reports of store managers, etc, whom the district managers can r/w/u/d etc.  Now, the complications: people at higher levels can make things visible to people at lower levels, either to individuals (department writes document to several specific stockers) users or everyone below them (store manager writes a memo to the entire store) or any permutation you can imagine. Also, individuals can create reports that their peers cannot see or they can choose grant access to store stockers in other districts etc.

We are considering an ACL with one permission per entity, but are worried about the large number of records that would create. Even if only a report was readable to everyone else in a department of 30 and every person above them [in the chain of command], creating a single report would require ~40 records! With 1 report per week per user that is 2000 permissions per user per year. 1,500 users means over 3,000,000 permissions per year.

It seems like a rule-engine based approach would be nice, but I have not seen any blogs or articles mentioning that approach so we're hesitant to that approach.

We are also considering some ACL/rule home-brew hybrid where you could grant permission to a department id with a discriminator of "manager" or "stockers" etc to subselect, but are worried that checking for all possible permissions (you could be granted permission specifically by another user, you have permission as a memeber of your department, you could have permission as a member of a store, or of district) sounds like an error-prone tedious nightmare.

What is the best approach for our application?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using Spring Security and ACL's - the nice thing about Springs ACL implementation is it is implemented with AoP it should be easier to integrate.

It sounds like your security requirements are quite complicated - off the top of my head I dont know how you'd implement this..  but you can reduce the number of records required by creating ACL's against your object hierarchy and having objects 'inherit' permissions from parent objects.  You grant a user read permissions to the parent **Department** of a **Report** - so they would inherit read access to the child reports of that department.  Alternatively a Manager might have read and update permissions on the Department. The key to all this is how your java object model has been structured.

I have had a similar situation in a system where there were thousands of articles in an object hierarchy of **Business Unit -- Publication -- Issue -- Article**.  You can have hierarchys of ACL's - so in my system - users that had C/R/W permissions to a particular business unit, inherited permissions on all child objects in the hierarchy.

Comment: Spring ACL is definitely a consideration. However, we would like to distribute the application and it is our understand that we would then have to create a new security context on the backend server for each call them. We don't want the security on the front-end so that we could reuse the security for alternate front-ends (potentially an iPad app) for example. It seems ugly and undesirable, but definitely doable.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Customization + Complexity = JBoss Drools, I don't have much experience using this technology but I believe it would be worth a look in your case, check out the latest drools samples at: http://blog.athico.com/2011/04/try-drools-example-in-less-than-minute.html